# scheduled timer does not end, if LongPressReconizerState is end

Tags: swift, timer, avaudioplayer, long-press

I try to build a Music player via AVAudioPlayer. My audioPlayer works!  Now I try build the rewind function, which is a bi-functional Button:

1. one Tap: the player starts from beginning (`player.currentTime = 0`) (works)
2. Longpess: the player start rewind in 0.5s steps, and end the "rewind process" if the button ist released

#### My code (abstract)

```
var player = AVAudioPlayer()
@IBOutlet weak var rewindButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:    #selector(rewindTapAction))  //Tap function will call when user tap on button
        let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rewindLongPressAction(_:))) //Long function will call when user long press on button.
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        rewindButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        rewindButton.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)
} 

@objc func rewindTapAction(){
    print("tapped")
    player.currentTime = TimeInterval(0)
}

@objc func rewindLongPressAction(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    print("longpress")
    var rewindTimer : Timer!

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began{
        print("longpress started")

        rewindTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { Timer in
                            self.player.currentTime = TimeInterval( self.player.currentTime - 0.5)
                            print("timer")
                        })

    }else if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended || gestureRecognizer.state == .cancelled{
        print("longpress ended")
        rewindTimer.invalidate()
    }

}
```

### My Problem is:

After I release the rewindButton (longpress), the rewind timer does not stop. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define rewindTimer outside the scope of the rewindLongPressAction function. When your function gets called again with gesture state .ended, it doesn't have the same reference to the rewindTimer anymore.